# Another probabilities problem

Tags: combinatorics

There are 12 signs of the Zodiac: Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, Scorpio, Sagittarius,
Capricorn, Aquarius, and Pisces. Each sign corresponds to a different calendar period of approximately 1
month. Assuming that a person is just as likely to be born under one sign as another, what is the probability
that in a group of 5 people at least two of them have the same sign?

[image: Here's my solution...But I think it's not right, even though the answer is Ok. My own solution seems weird to me.]

Here's my solution...But I think it's not right, even though the answer is Ok. My own solution seems weird to me.

Comment: How did you come up with your solution?  If you have some logic behind it, it shouldn't seem weird.  You could read about the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) to see the calculation with $365$ instead of $12$.  The logic is the same.

Comment: I wrote down 1*1/12*2/12*3/12*4/12*5/12, assumed that is a probability of getting same match. This multiplied by C(10, 5) is the reversed answer.

Comment: Solved it. 
1 - 12/12*11/12*10/12*9/12*8/12 = 89/144

Answer (score 0):

Well since the probability for a person being born in one zodiac sign in $\frac{1}{12}$ you can use this formula to find probability for at least 2 people being born in same sign...that means at most 5 people can be born in same sign.

$\binom{5}{2}(\frac{1}{12})^2(\frac{1}{12})^3$+$\binom{5}{3}(\frac{1}{12})^3(\frac{1}{12})^2$+$\binom{5}{4}(\frac{1}{12})^4(\frac{1}{12})^1$+$\binom{5}{5}(\frac{1}{12})^5(\frac{1}{12})^0$

Comment: I get (1/12)^5 * (C(5,2) + C(5,3) + C(5,4) + C(5,5))
Am I wrong? If no, then this must be wrong.

Comment: Yes , it should be that.